# Python: Using setter inside class init for a private attribute

Tags: python, class, properties, initialization, setter

I'm trying to create a private attribute in the class initialization, using parameters described in the setter.

I can do it by typing the same code twice, but I'd like to keep the checks inside the setter.

This works:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        if length >= 0:
            self.__length = length
        else:
            self.__length = 0

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.__length
    
    @length.setter
    def length(self, length: int):
        if length >= 0:
            self.__length = length
        else:
            self.__length = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Example(43)
    print(test.length)
    test = Example(-10)
    print(test.length)
```

But I'm trying to find a way to do it so that I don't have to repeat the same checks in both the init and the setter, but rather call the setter from the init.

After reviewing another stackoverflow answer, this also works:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.__length = length
        self.length = length

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.__length
    
    @length.setter
    def length(self, length: int):
        if length >= 0:
            self.__length = length
        else:
            self.__length = 0
```

But now I'm confused by there apparently being two identically named attributes, one private and one public. The python visualizer however only shows there being one (private) attribute. Is this the correct way to do this? Am I not creating two separate attributes with similar names?

Comment: You could remove `self.__length = length` from the constructor in the second piece of code - it's superfluous because the next line `self.length = length` invokes the setter.

Comment: This ^, and using double underscore (and name mangling) is discouraged in general. Private is with single underscore by convention.

Comment: That works, but am I not creating a public attribute if I only use "self.length"? Or does the setter take care of it being private?
The assignment I'm doing calls for double underscores, not my choice.

Comment: `self.length` is the property implemented by your getter and setter: `self.length = length` in the constructor doesn't create a new attribute separate from that property; it invokes the setter. (The code inside the constructor can't run before the class definition has been processed, so the property is guaranteed to exist when the constructor code runs.)

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but here it is how typically properties are used to sanitize data:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.length = length  # This calls the setter of the length property

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length  # One underscore is the convention for private attributes
    
    @length.setter
    def length(self, length: int):
        if length >= 0:
            self._length = length
        else:
            self._length = 0
```

```
>>> ex = Example(-1)
>>> ex.length
0
>>> ex._length
0
>>> ex.length = 1
>>> ex._length 
1
```